# Ideas for embedded application that uses POST and GET to interact with the internet

Tags: html, embedded, iot

I am trying to do a project where I use POST and GET html requests to do something cool on the internet. I am using an alpha version of a Redpine signals board (they gave use exclusive access for a class at my university).

My problem is *I don't really know much about html requests*.

Is it possible to do something simple like post a twitter status using only POST and/or GET?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can do that. Many web services offer an API that lets you interact with the service via http. Twitter is one of these services; check out their REST api documentation: https://dev.twitter.com/rest/public

Here's the endpoint to POST an update: https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/post/statuses/update

I'd guess the trickiest thing for you will be figuring out the auth... start here: https://dev.twitter.com/oauth/overview/introduction

Comment: yeah im not exactly sure how we would "log in" to the account we make with the board.

Comment: @user8363 depending on how deep you're trying to go with this experiment, you're going to have to learn at least something about OAuth. Unfortunately it's kind of complicated. I think https://aaronparecki.com/articles/2012/07/29/1/oauth2-simplified explains it fairly coherently.

Comment: Alternatively, if your goal is just 'do something nifty', you may want to pick some other API with simpler or no authentication. https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=7546040

Comment: @user8363 for example, Facebook is a lot easier. You can find a token for your account at https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/ and then use it in a request like `GET https://graph.facebook.com/v2.3/me?access_token=YOUR_LONG_FACEBOOK_ACCESS_TOKEN_HERE` -- remember that token is more or less a password to your account, so guard it carefully.

Answer (score 0):

Twitter would be a great place to start!
Check out their [documentation](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/post/statuses/update) for it.